# How to grant limited permissions to PostgreSQL tables?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am considering switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL because of the limitations of MySQL's fulltext features in a shared hosting environment (the minimum word length cannot be changed). I have no administrative experience of PostgreSQL and am struggling to make sense of granting permissions to users/roles.

My app has two users, one for building and one for runtime. I want the runtime user just to have these perms:

```
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
```

I therefore log onto PostgreSQL thus:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Having consulted the manuals and various internet sources, I created this demo, with the intention of having limited permissions on all future tables. From a completely fresh database:

```
CREATE USER job_frontend PASSWORD 'password';
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS job_frontend;
CREATE DATABASE job_frontend ENCODING 'UTF8';
CREATE ROLE job_runtime;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO job_runtime;
GRANT job_runtime TO job_frontend;
```

My strategy, which is probably where I am going wrong: create a user, set grants on a role, then assign the role grants to the user. Do I need to remove some default permissions from the database? In MySQL, users have no permissions by default, and it is probably in this mindset I am stuck.

I then use PDO/PHP to try various operations (of course I modify the `prepare()` to run the item I want:

```
<?php

$dsn  = 'pgsql:dbname=job_frontend;host=localhost;user=job_frontend;password=password';
$db = new PDO($dsn);

// These should succeed
$sqlRead = "SELECT * FROM x";
$sqlWrite = "INSERT INTO x (id) VALUES (1)";

// This should fail but in fact succeeds
$sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE x (id INTEGER)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sqlRead);
if ($stmt === false)
{
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
}

$stmt->execute();
echo "Count: " . $stmt->rowCount() . "\n";

if ($rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    print_r($rows);
}
```

As per the comment, the `CREATE TABLE` succeeds, but I don't want it to. What am I missing?

I believe the shared PostgreSQL environment will be 8.3, but a later one may become available in the future (I note this as I see there are various grant options not available until 9.x). I am running 9.3 locally to test things, but would like to keep it compatible with 8.3 for now (until the later version comes online).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anybody can do all in schema "public" by default.

```
postgres=# CREATE ROLE tom LOGIN; -- user without rights
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# SET role tom ;
SET
postgres=> CREATE TABLE bubu(a int);
CREATE TABLE
```

you have to remove CREATE right from PUBLIC on public schema where is by default.

```
postgres=# REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
REVOKE
postgres=# SET role tom;
SET
postgres=> CREATE TABLE foo(a int);
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE foo(a int);
                     ^
```

Comment: Aha, thanks. So would I be best creating everything in my own schema then, so explicit permissions can be added, or is it quite usual to use the `public` one (and then revoke as you say)?

Comment: Depends, what do you do. From my perspective both by you described ways are +/- same. You can do "public" schema less public or you can create own schema and direct default table searching there via `search_path`. Result is exactly same. One is "Oracle" like way, second "MySQL" like way - but zero diff between.

Comment: Alrighty, thank you - I will give this a try and report back!

Comment: Just a thought: in a shared hosting environment, is the `public` schema visible to all users? If so that would point to me creating my own, I would guess?

Comment: I am expecting so other users will not have access to your database - so access to public schema is effectively disabled. But it is not PostgreSQL default - although I am expecting so it have to be default on shared hostings. PostgreSQL has little bit different philosophy than MySQL - it doesn't try to protect database schema - but it protects data very well. When you remove `USAGE` right from `PUBLIC`, then your "public" schema is hidden from other users.

Comment: Alright, I will create some database users when I get that hosting set up, and see what each can see. In the meantime, `REVOKE CREATE` above has done the trick `:-)`.